# Passing Array of Objects into Angular Directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have an array of objects in my angular controller, e.g.

```
[{
   label: 'label1',
   data: [{
             type: TimelineChart.TYPE.POINT,
             at: new Date([2015, 1, 1])
           }, {
             type: TimelineChart.TYPE.POINT,
             at: new Date([2015, 2, 1])
         }]
 }, {
   label: 'label2',
   data: [{
             type: TimelineChart.TYPE.POINT,
             at: new Date([2015, 1, 11])
         }, {
             type: TimelineChart.TYPE.POINT,
             at: new Date([2015, 1, 15])
         }]
 }];
```

Every object has a `Date` field. How can I pass this array of objects into my directive?

I tried passing by reference:

```
<div id= "chart" my-directive my-data="data"></div>
$scope: {
          myData: '='
        },
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        function init() {
          var data = $scope.myData;
          var timeline = new TimelineChart($element[0], data);
        }

        $attrs.$observe("myData", init);
      }
```

However, it didn't work. I get `undefined`.

Passing in as an attribute, i.e. `my-data="{{ data }}"` and using `JSON.parse($attrs.myData)` does not work due to the `Date` fields.

Comment: Use $observe or even better $watch arguments to make sure that the new value is defined. Or pass promise from controller or service

Comment: I can confirm that it is well-defined in the controller but for some reason, it is showing up as `undefined` in my directive. @charlietfl Also, I am already using `$observe`.

Comment: Yes but `$observe` can fire with first value which if you are using `$http` to create data won't be defined then...use the arguments. Or... use routing resolve and make sure everything is ready before controller and directive even fire

Comment: I am not even calling `$http` to retrieve the data right now... I am simply defining it in controller. @charlietfl

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple to pass the data to `directive`. I think what you are missing is scope. You are using `$scope` instead of `scope`. Directive Definition object takes `scope` not `$scope`. So what you need to do it.

```
scope: { //make it scope
          myData: '='
        },
link: function($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        function init() {
          var data = $scope.myData;
          var timeline = new TimelineChart($element[0], data);
        }

        $attrs.$observe("myData", init);
      }
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qsf82467/)

Comment: What challenge you are facing you. I have created the fiddle I can see I am able to get the data

Comment: I am not able to see your fiddle; it isn't running, so I can't say if it is working. But I do know that even if I switch to using `scope`in my code, it doesn't work.

Comment: I can see data in console. Please check the console once.

Answer (score -2):

I think the problem is your array object is lost in $scope . For confirmation, use console.log($scope.myData);

And see in browser console what it returns, if undefined then simply write console.log($scope); and then run the application . **Go to browser console and expand $parent until you find myData object**. Count the number of parent scope.

If suppose you found it under 3rd parent ,the use

**$scope.$parent.$parent.$parent.myData instead of $scope.myData .**

This will work :)